# ios libxml recup console message in xmlSchemaValidateDoc

Tags: ios, libxml2

I'm using libxml in my ios project.

I validate XML doc with a schema XML and everything goes well, cool !

I'm using : int error = xmlSchemaValidateDoc(validityContext, doc);

My question is : this error (int) it's ok but my console show me an error message very intersting ! Is there a way to intercept this message ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is xmlSchemaSetValidErrors in libxml. It's usefull to get the message !